# Hardy–Littlewood Tauberian theorem for Laplace transform

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, laplace-transform, tauberian-theorems

The Hardy–Littlewood Tauberian theorem for Laplace transform in Chapter XIII in "An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications" by Feller reads as follows

Let $F : [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ of bounded variation, $p \geq 0$ be real number and
$$\omega_F(s) = \int^\infty_0 e^{-st} d F(t).$$
Then each of the relations
$$ \dfrac{\omega_F(\tau \lambda)}{\omega_F(\tau)} \to \lambda^{-p}\hspace{15pt} \text{as $\tau \to 0$}.$$
$$ \dfrac{F(tx)}{F(t)} \to x^{p} \hspace{15pt} \text{as $t \to \infty$}.$$
implies the other as well as
$$ \omega_F(1/t) \sim F(t) \Gamma(p+1) \hspace{15pt} \text{as $t \to \infty$}.$$

I have three questions.

1. First, generally, what is the condition for the existence of an inverse Laplace transform?
2. Second, I am so doubious that this Tauberian theorem is true for $p=0$. The inverse Laplace transform of $1$ is $\delta(t)$: then, in this case is it true that
   $$
   \dfrac{\omega_F(\tau \lambda)}{\omega_F(\tau)} \to 1 \implies \dfrac{F(tx)}{F(t)} \to H(t)
   $$
   where $H(t)$ is the Heaviside step function, rather than converging to $1$?
3. Finally, the third question is: do the Tauberian theorem for the Laplace transform holds in the form
   $$
   F(s) = \displaystyle\int^\infty_0 e^{-st} f(t) dt,
   $$ namely does it implies the asymptotic relation between $F$ and $f$?

Thanks!!!

Comment: I can not find this book, could you provide the link of this? Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I have read several books about Laplace Transform, but I can not find the answers.

Comment: Sorry, my memory failed. The author is actually Widder.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! This book settled question 2. But I can not find answers for questions 1 and 3. For question 3, I have read through chapter 5 about the tauberian theorem but I do not find out any useful stuff. For question 1, should the condition be the one tgat the mellin inverse  integral is convergent?

Answer (score 1):

Just to get a few points :) , let me repeat my comment : part of the answer is contained in Widder's book **Laplace transform**.

Comment: I finally get the results from the book, thanks!

Comment: Can you perhaps elaborate?  (As it stands, this answer is not much more than a link-only answer.)